# MYSQL Filter keys older than X days and don't repeat less than X days

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a list of `keys`, `buckets` and `time`

```
Key   Bucket   Time
1     A        x
1     B        x
1     C        x
2     A        x
3     A        x
4     A        x
1     A        y
```

I want to get a list that has keys that are >= `x` time and doesn't repeat between `y` and `x` time.  In the table above all keys have a time >= `x` but the last key has been touched and will remove the `1  A  x` from the list resulting in something like this

```
Key Bucket 
1   B
1   C
2   A
3   A
4   A
```

I'm trying to do this in MySQL and I'm very new and very confused by SQL documentation.

I've tried something like this... I have no idea what it's trying to do.

```
SELECT keyname, bucket, log.time FROM log INNER JOIN (SELECT time FROM log GROUP BY keyname) dup ON log.time = dup.time;
```

Hope I've described the problem well enough.

EDIT:

key is a string

bucket is a string

time is a time object like "15/May/2013:18:35:03 +0000"

Comment: What kind of column is time?  What does the actual data look like?

Comment: @StevenMoseley does the edit help?

Comment: To clarify, when you say "I want to get a list that has keys that are >= x time and doesn't repeat < x" I assume the first "x" is a DateTime, and the second "x" is an integer (count)?

Comment: @StevenMoseley `x` is the same time.  The key doesn't repeat between now and `x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you want to get the most recent records based on the `Time` field while only returning unique combinations of Key+Bucket.

To do that:

```
SELECT `Key`, `Bucket`, MAX(`Time`) FROM `log` GROUP BY `Key`, `Bucket`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I get you correctly now, here's your answer.  This will return log results where there's only one match in the given time range.

So if there are two matches found, it eliminates both of them, right?

```
SELECT `keyname`, `bucket`, MAX(`time`)
FROM `log` 
WHERE `time` > 'x'
GROUP BY `keyname`, `bucket`
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```